# Storing javascript variable into a HTML text box

Tags: javascript, html, gps, geolocation

I am using the HTML5 Geolocation and want to store the latitude and longitude into two separate text boxes instead of being simply displayed on the screen

Below is the code:

```
Current Location: <BR>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Locate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
}

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a pair of textboxes on the page, and set their `value`s.

```
Current Location: <BR>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Locate</button>
<p id="demo">
    Latitude: <input type="text" id="lat">
    Longitude: <input type="text" id="lon">
</p>

<script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
}

    function showPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("lon").value = position.coords.longitude;

}
</script>
```

You could also do this by writing out the textboxes with JavaScript:

```
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: <input type='text' id='lat' value='" + position.coords.latitude + "'> " + 
        "Longitude: <input type='text' id='lon' value='" + position.coords.longitude + "'> ";


}
```

Comment: Well yes but you could also generate the textboxes if they dont already exist

Comment: @DustinPoissant See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two textboxes that you want to set the values in are:

```
Latitude: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Longitude: <input type="text" id="long">
```

You can add following line to your JS to pick the appropriate textbox and store the value.

```
document.getElementById("lat").setAttribute("value", position.coords.latitude);
```